# Questions on equivalence relation and functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I just found this question in my discrete math homework and just can't have the solution by looking through the textbook.

The question contains two parts:

a) If  $R$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$, is $R$ necessarily a function $A\rightarrow A$?

b) If  $R$ is an partial order relation on set $A$, is $R$ necessarily a function $A\rightarrow A$?

Can anyone give some tips? I hope you can tell from the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \mathbb N$.

For a) if $R = \{(a,b) \mid a = b \mod 2\}$, can you find two different values $x,y \in \mathbb N$ such that $(2,x) \in R$ and $(2,y) \in R$?

Can you find a similar example for b)?

Comment: thanks for inspiration, however what does a=b mod 2 mean?

Comment: @hoho97 it means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $2$. In other words, $(a,b) \in R$ if both $a$ and $b$ are even, or both $a$ and $b$ are odd.